# Reference for the rate of divergence of Harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

In the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) it states that the rate of divergence of Harmonic series is

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} < \log n +1 $

I have tried to find a reference, other than wikipedia, for this bound  but with no success. Which is a good reference for the above bound?

Comment: Try a Riemann sum for $\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: IIRC, this is easy to do yourself; repeat wikipedia's "integral test" argument, but aiming to get an upper bound rather than a lower bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bound is obtained by approximating the sum by definite integrals (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals)). We obtain
$$
\log(n+1)=\int_1^{n+1}\frac1x\mathrm dx\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le1+\int_1^n\frac1x\mathrm dx=1+\log n.
$$
This also shows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim \log n\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty,
$$
where $a_n\sim b_n$ denotes the fact that $a_n/b_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the sum as a the sum of the area of $n$ rectangles of size $1\times\frac{1}{k}, \ k=1,\dots,n$ you can bound by an integral.